# Remove folders from left panel in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

In the default file manager for Debian, how do I remove the folders bookmarked on the left panel? I have no use for most of the folders there.

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-the-nautilus-sidebar) answer help?

Answer (score 10):

Just in case someone finds this thread, I managed to do it following the guidelines listed here:
[Ask Ubuntu - removing bookmarks from nautilus sidebar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-the-nautilus-sidebar)

Modifying this file let me remove some useless folders (tested on Gnome 3)

`<your favorite text editor> ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Comment: That's right, but it was already linked to in Proletariat's comment.

Comment: @pierreB I see - sorry. Should this be closed as duplicate then?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend editing that file, since other applications rely on it